# Synology NAS: SMS Alerts are not parsed correctly

Tags: notifications, synology, sms

In the past I've set up the SMS notifications service on my Synology NAS (DSM 6.2.2-24922 ) through ClickaTell.

Now whenever I receive a SMS notification every message looks like this:

> @ W @ A @ R @ N @ I @ N @ G @ @ F @ A @ I @ L @ E @ D @ @ @ @

and so on..

The language setting is Dutch for the notifications.

Anybody else has experienced this issue too?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Created new SMS provider. Make sure you have accoutn with clickatell.com and ave setup API Id, and tested within clickatell.com web site.

On NAS
Add SMS provider
Edit/use following url-Change user,password, api_id and to

https://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=TestUser&password=TestPassword&api_id=3148203&to=886123456789&text=Hello+world

then press next twice and select parameters.

See https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=19799